# Dual Window Regulators

Tags: window, vintage

[image]

I'm not sure if this is an appropriate place to ask this question, but does anyone know why a car would need two window regulators per door?  I can't figure out which car this is, so I don't even know what to look for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some older cars have more than one controllable "window" on the door, so there needs to be more than one window crank.  For example, here's a photo showing a car door with 2 window cranks.  You can tell that there's 2 different pieces of the window that can be controlled.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One is the side glass regulator (long handle), the other (short handle) is the wing vent regulator.